# How to make drag to expand & resize animated view in React Native

Tags: react-native, draggable, react-native-modal, panresponder

Need a drag to expand and resize the view like in the photo

[image: Image animation that I need]

Tried many react native libraries like react-native-draggable-view & react-native-modalize but could not found a suitable solution.

This GIF is picked from the GoJek app.

Comment: Well, if you didn't find it helpful. Try this [one](https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel).


if this is also not what you are looiking for, then i believe you can create your own using modal,view, touchable and some more components.

Comment: @DaniyalShaikh I've tried like this too. Thanks for your response.